# How to stop the paid app to be transfered by Bluetooth? Does Google Play provide Google Play login id after each download?

Tags: android, security

I developed a paid app... but if someone downloads it then he can transfer it to another mobile through Bluetooth file transfer app. I want to know how to prevent that. If is there any way to get email id after downloading app from google play then I am able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

A general answer is: use [Application Licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) provided by Google Play.